# ffmpeg embed several images in video at different points in time

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, embedding

I am trying to embed various images in a video using ffmpeg. So far I have:

```
ffmpeg -i testclip.mp4 -i question2.png -i question1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=(W-w)/2:20:enable='between(t,2,5)'; [0:v][1:v] overlay=(W-w)/2:20:enable='between(t,10,15)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy 123.mp4
```

This however will only embed the first image. Is there a way to ambed multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out:

```
ffmpeg -i testclip.mp4 -i question2.png -i question1.png -filter_complex "[0][1] overlay=(W-w)/2:20:enable='between(t,2,5)'[q1]; [q1][2] overlay=(W-w)/2:20:enable='between(t,10,15)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy 123.mp4
```